# How to hide my Android WiFi hotspot from being detected?

Tags: networking, wifi-hotspot

I have a Samsung Galaxy Young phone and a 3G connection. I use my phone as a wireless modem, but I don't want other devices to find my WiFi hotspot when they search for WiFi.

How can I stop other devices from seeing my hotspot?

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is the ability to hide the SSID.

Depending upon your phone and service provider, you may have an option to configure "Hide my device" for the hotspot.  My Samsung (with Android 4.4.2) has that option and it appears to work.

However, there seem to be plenty of other phones/provider combinations that don't appear to provide this feature, or, they don't work correctly as evidenced by [this discussion on a 3rd-party app for enabling tethering via WiFi](https://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/issues/detail?id=16).

Answer (score 2):

Don't waste your time trying to hide your hot spot - you can't really.

What you CAN do however is to require a password to allow a connection TO your hot spot.

In some cases, not sure here as I do not have your device, it is possible to lock the hot spot and only allow connections from one (or more, if there are others who also need to connect) specified MAC addresses only.

Answer (score 1):

A strong password is your best protection. "Hidden" signals are open invites to hackers who will see you as frightened and defeneseless prey. Hackers only see a fun new target to seek and destroy. You stand out like a sore thumb when you attempt to hide. ATTEMPT to hide. Doesn't work or everybody would do it.